# Apache Webserver Modifying Config or Re-direct has no effect

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

I'm new to Apache webserver so I may just be doing something obvious incorrectly.

I installed 'OwnCloud' via the Debian package manager which by default also installs Apache webserver. The basic installations works OK and I can use OwnCloud fine.

I now want to enable https connections and redirect all http requests to https however I cannot get the redirect to work. Whilst trying to understand and resolve the problem it also appears as though Apache is ignoring changes to the configuration file, e.g. changing the DocumentRoot of the default VirtualHost has no effect.

As it's a Debian installation I understand the configuration files are in slightly different locations to that of a standard Apache install.

In the `sites-available` directory I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    #       ServerName <removed_for_privacy>
    #       Redirect permanent / https://<removed_for_privacy>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   Redirect / https://<removed_for_privacy>/owncloud
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost <removed_for_privacy>:80>
    ServerName <removed_for_privacy>
    Redirect permanent /owncloud https://<removed_for_privacy>/owncloud
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

In the above I have replaced the servername with `<removed_for_privacy>`

I've also created a specific `owncloud-ssl.conf` file in the same directory in an attempt to get it to work:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost <removed_for_privacy>:443>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/<removed_for_privacy>.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/<removed_for_privacy>.key

</VirtualHost>
```

The https works fine if I manually type it but I want to redirect http requests to https but the redirect never occurs.

Also just out of experimentation I tried to change the DocumentRoot to a sub directory of the standard `/var/www` but after restarting Apache it still looks at `/var/www` and not the sub-directory within.

Any help appreciated.

**Update**

I've tried deleting the 000-default.conf and bizarrely apache continues to respond to http requests! Surely with this file removed it should complain/fall over? I haven't a clue how it's being configured...

Comment: Did you reload the apache service after making the config changes? The active config files are under `sites-enabled` - these should be links to files under `sites-available`.

Comment: Yes reloaded the apache service after changes were made. Just checked and there has been a link created under `sites-enabled` to the `owncloud-ssl.conf` file in `sites-available`. Still not working though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use mod_rewrite option,then add following configuration to **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Make sure you have something as follows in httpd.conf (mod_rewrite support):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```